# Unexpected NPE in OncreateView

Tags: java, android

I am sending data from activity to fragment and starting the fragment with following code:

```
if (conversation != null) {
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    ConversationFragment conv = new ConversationFragment();
    frgObj = ConversationFragment.newInstance(conversation);
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container, frgObj, "ConversationFragment");
    fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
    fragmentTransaction.commitAllowingStateLoss();
}
```

Here my fragment methods:

```
   static Conversation activeConversation;
    public static ConversationFragment newInstance(Conversation _activeConversation){
            ConversationFragment fragment = new ConversationFragment();
            activeConversation=_activeConversation;
            return  fragment;
    }



@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_conversation, container, false);

        ...
        Long conversationId = activeConversation.getId();
        ...
    }
```

This is working well on my simulator and test device. But when i look to play store crash reports i saw some users getting null pointer exception for `activeConversation.getId()`

What can be cause to this problem and how can i resolve it?

Comment: Using static fields in Android is **always** a bad idea! The NPE is thrown because `activeConversation` is not set yet or has been reset to `null`.

Comment: I know it is null but what to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should always use fragment arguments for passing data to the fragment.

Here is a situation when your app crashes. User starts the activity with your fragment. You pass data to the fragment via parameters. The instance is created properly. Now user goes to some other application and your app goes to the background. At some point if user is not using it anymore, the Android system will kill the activity but it will remember where the user left off, so that the state can be recreated once the user is back. In this scenario it knows which activity and which fragment to create. In this case it will use a default constructor to create a fragment. Since the default constructor doesn't fill up the static `activeConversation` the app crashes in `onCreateView`.

Instead, in your `newInstance`, put this information into arguments bundle and then use it in your `onCreateView`. More info here: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment#setArguments(android.os.Bundle)

The fragment's arguments are maintained during the fragment recreation.

Comment: How can i pass the conversation object with Bundle class?

Comment: It depends on what conversation object is. Possible ways are: make it implement `Parcelable` interface OR encode it to a `String` and parse back, e.g. via Json, OR store it somewhere on disk and use an identifier to retrieve it in a fragment OR store in somewhere in a state which can be accessed by a fragment directly. Which one to use really depends on your use case.

Comment: What happens if i store it in activity then access with interface to this variable?

Comment: That will work. Although, keep in mind that if it's going to be non-static, then you will still need to use `Bundle` in activity's `onSaveInstanceState` in order to not lose the object during recreation. If you want to make it static, then the object will always be in memory until the app is completely finished. The fragment will be able to access it with no problem. But in this case make sure the object is not too heavy and it doesn't keep references to your activity context. Otherwise you will have a memory leak.

Comment: Another downside of having it in activity is the app design. Basically you require the outbounding activity to have an interface which should provide this object which makes the fragment more dependent on its activity. Maybe not really a big deal in your case, but in general it's a good practice to make the fragment as independent as possible from other fragments and activities. In the long run it makes your app more flexible.